# Show stackLabels at both top and bottom in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am using Stacked and grouped column where I needed to show stack name on the bottom and stack total on top of the stack.

JSFiddle link: [Stacked and grouped](https://jsfiddle.net/shak_imran/c4zsq59m/)

Found another way to do it but having problem with stack labels.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/shak_imran/k58whtbx/5/`
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt breaks the **stackLabel** calculations logic - implementing this type of solution will require some changes in the core code.

I think that a better solution will be rendering those labels under columns. Here is a guideline how to achieve it:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akoeyq5m/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      stackMale = chart.yAxis[0].stacks['column,male,,'],
      stackFemale = chart.yAxis[0].stacks['column,female,,'];

    // Male label
    for (let i in stackMale) {
      let x = stackMale[i].label.x + chart.plotLeft,
        y = chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop,
        labelBBox;

      if (stackMale[i].customLabel) {
        stackMale[i].customLabel.destroy();
      }
      stackMale[i].customLabel = chart.renderer.text('Male', x, y)
        .add();
      labelBBox = stackMale[i].customLabel.getBBox();
      stackMale[i].customLabel.translate(-labelBBox.width / 2, labelBBox.height)
    }

    // Female label
    for (let i in stackFemale) {
      let x = stackFemale[i].label.x + chart.plotLeft,
        y = chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop,
        labelBBox;
      if (stackFemale[i].customLabel) {
        stackFemale[i].customLabel.destroy();
      }
      stackFemale[i].customLabel = chart.renderer.text('Female', x, y)
        .add();
      labelBBox = stackFemale[i].customLabel.getBBox();
      stackFemale[i].customLabel.translate(-labelBBox.width / 2, labelBBox.height)
    }

  }
}
```

Feel free to test and improve this code. If something is unclear - just ask.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render